# Setting up custom email addresses for domain bought from Digital Ocean

Tags: digital-ocean

I have a domain name hosted on digital ocean, 'www.mydomain.com' and hosting an application made in django. I need to create an email address 'me@mydomain.com'. I have searched on a way to do this from start to finish but cant get a definite answer. Need some guidance.

Comment: This question is not related to Django, but a general problem how to setup email infrastructure for your domain and not strictly a programming question. ServerFault would be a better forum.

Comment: digital ocean sells domains?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Digital Ocean does not provide an e-mail component. You can either install and setup your own e-mail server from scratch, which you don't want to do. Or use an e-mail hosting service provider, zoho.com is a free one. There are others. Rackspace, and Google offer e-mail host solutions, but they are both fee-based.

Once you sign up for an e-mail hosting account, zoho.com or whichever e-mail service provider you choose will provide you with an MX record setup. You will then add an MX record to your DNS records on your Digital Ocean domain.

This will connect your domain name to the e-mail hosting service.

After this, you need to setup your e-mail on the e-mail hosting service. THis is a non-trival task and you'll have to do reading on SMTP, POP, IMAP etc. There is plenty of help on the zoho site.

Make sure to test sending and receiving e-mails to make sure the setup is working.

Once you have working e-mail on your domain, then you can move on to using it in your Django app.